# C Code: To connect a pty terminal to current process to execute commands

Tags: c, unix, tty, ioctl, pty

In a Unix Process, I am planning to write code to access terminal. So, I can login to process and run few commands.

For example, 
I can do telnet 0:2000 to get my terminal and from there I can dump my commands to dump process information.

On my research, I saw that I can use /dev/pts or /dev/tty to the access terminal for the process. User can login to terminal to these but not clear on how it is works.

Comment: I seriously hope you're not actually running a telnet server ... *please* use `sshd`.

Answer (score 4):

To create a new pseudoterminal, tou need to call the following functions in order:

- `posix_openpt` (To get a new master)
- `grantpt` (To fix permissions for the new slave)
- `unlockpt` (To unlock the slave)
- `ptsname` (To get the name of the slave)
- `open` (To open the slave)
- `setsid` (optional, to enter a new session and process group - typically after fork when you are running a separate process on the slave)

Comment: Thank you @o11c, this will actually open a xterm model terminal but that is not what I am looking for.  I don't want any new xterm open. Something like following .consider we have process X running .. (and opened 2002 port to listen connections  

     $telnet 0:2002  
           -> print this  
           -> this  
           -> exit

Comment: Huh? Note that you don't have to do anything *graphical* with a pty, you can just process it directly in a program

Comment: Yes, I agree, But I need to open at one pty or tty or port to listen continuously. So, My Program will be having two process. One will be doing its work or execution. Other thread/Process will open a at one tty or port will continuously listen to User Commands. For This I need to attach to either port or any tty/pty. So, user can access that terminal and can run commands.

Comment: I'm still quite confused about what you're saying. Do you want just a client-server architecture? Do you want to spawn an `xterm` with all its I/O redirected to your process?

Comment: OP wants to connect a terminal emulator (i.e. `xterm`) to an *already running* and *remote* process via some ipv4 address:port and then (OP believes) it would act as if the said remote process was launched locally via a shell or something in the sense that OP can enter text and the remote process receives it as via `stdin` (like a normal terminal application, launched locally) and remote process writes in `stdout` and the terminal emulator on the other ends shows it as if ... well you get the picture :D